how can I fix my app crashing in my expo?
I was building a mini app with expo and after installing it to my device by compiling expo cli by both APK and aab, in both cases when I reached this page it crashed, it worked everything except when I go to the dynamic page. but I saw this error on my cli while compiling and it asks me to update my packages....enter image description here
this is the code and folder structure enter image description here
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Linking,
  StyleSheet,
  ToastAndroid,
} from "react-native";
import BottomSheet, {
  BottomSheetBackdrop,
  BottomSheetView,
} from "@gorhom/bottom-sheet";
import { useCallback, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";

import RadioGroup from "react-native-radio-buttons-group";
import Button from "./Button";

const ActionSheet = ({ bottomSheetRef }) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false); // Track bottom sheet state

  const snapPoints = useMemo(() => ["55%"], []);

  const openModal = () => {
    setIsOpen(false); // Close the bottom sheet
  };

  const [isPregnant, setIsPregnant] = useState(false); // Yes/No for pregnancy
  const [needsAmbulance, setNeedsAmbulance] = useState(false); // Yes/No for ambulance
  const [damageLevel, setDamageLevel] = useState(""); // Hard, Medium, Low
  const [paymentMethod, setPaymentMethod] = useState(""); // Payment method selection

  const handlePregnancySelection = (value) => setIsPregnant(value);
  const handleAmbulanceSelection = (value) => setNeedsAmbulance(value);
  const handleDamageSelection = (value) => setDamageLevel(value);
  const handlePaymentSelection = (value) => setPaymentMethod(value);

  const renderBackdrop = useCallback(
    (props) => (
      <BottomSheetBackdrop
        {...props}
        disappearsOnIndex={-1}
        appearsOnIndex={0}
        onPress={openModal}
      />
    ),
    []
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isOpen) {
      setIsOpen(false); 
    }
  }, []); 
  const radioButtons = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        id: "1",
        label: "Yes",
        value: "yes",
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        label: "No",
        value: "no",
      },
    ],
    []
  );
  const damagelevel = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        id: "1", 
        label: "Samll",
        value: "small",
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        label: "Medium",
        value: "medium",
      },
      {
        id: "3",
        label: "Hard",
        value: "hard",
      },
    ],
    []
  );
   const emergencybutton = useMemo(
     () => [
       {
         id: "1", 
         label: "Yes",
         value: "yes",
       },
       {
         id: "2",
         label: "No",
         value: "no",
       },
     ],
     []
   );

   const exitBotomSheet = () => {
    bottomSheetRef.current?.close()
    ToastAndroid.show("Request sent successfully! The ambulance will arrive soon.", ToastAndroid.SHORT);
   }

  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState();
  const [emergency, setEmergency] = useState();
  const [damage, setdamege] = useState();
  return (
    <BottomSheet
      style={styles.container}
      ref={bottomSheetRef}
      enablePanDownToClose={true}
      snapPoints={snapPoints}
      index={isOpen ? 0 : -1} 
      backdropComponent={renderBackdrop}
    >
      <View>
        <Text className="text-center text-2xl font-bold underline">Emergency Information</Text>
      </View>
      <View className="flex flex-col justify-between px-4 gap-y-3 mt-4">
        <View>
          <Text className="text-base">Are you pregnant lady?</Text>

          <RadioGroup
            radioButtons={radioButtons}
            onPress={setSelectedId}
            selectedId={selectedId}
            layout="row"
          />
        </View>
        <View>
          <Text className="text-base">Is it emergency?</Text>

          <RadioGroup
            radioButtons={emergencybutton}
            onPress={setEmergency}
            selectedId={emergency}
            layout="row"
          />
        </View>
        <View>
          <Text className="text-base">What is the damage level?</Text>

          <RadioGroup
            radioButtons={damagelevel}
            onPress={setdamege}
            selectedId={damage}
            layout="row"
          />
        </View>
      </View>

  <Button title={"Done"} handlePress={exitBotomSheet}/>
    </BottomSheet>
  );
};

export default ActionSheet;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 24,
    backgroundColor: "grey",
  },
  contentContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});








I tried to compile it in both aab and apk still the same issue.,I am using expo map and gorhom bottom sheet
